# Set table values on pyqt5 in pageload throws AttributeError

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to set pyqt5 Qtablewidget items on pageload using a helper class and method. This is my code.

```
#ui - > UI mainwindow class
#examdetails -> a list of dictionaries (table from database)  
def setExamRecords(self,ui,examDetails):
    for rowIndex,exam in enumerate(examDetails):
        for colIndex,key in enumerate(exam):
            print(exam[key])
            item = ui.tableWidget.item(rowIndex, colIndex)
            item.setText(str(exam[key]))
    return True
```

However this returns error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setText'`

is it not possible to set the ui elements in a separate class like this? The reason to moving to a separate helper class is mainly to reduce the codes clogging up in the main ui class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of an empty cell does not imply that it is associated with a QTableWidgetItem, therefore the item() method returns None. A possible solution is to check if it is None or not, if it is then create the QTableWidgetItem and set it with setItem():

```py
def setExamRecords(self, ui, examDetails):
    for rowIndex, exam in enumerate(examDetails):
        for colIndex, key in enumerate(exam):
            print(exam[key])
            item = ui.tableWidget.item(rowIndex, colIndex)
            if item is None:
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                ui.tableWidget.setItem(rowIndex, colIndex, item)
            item.setText(str(exam[key]))
    return True
```

Another possible solution is to use the model where if each cell is associated with a QModelIndex:

```py
def setExamRecords(self, ui, examDetails):
    for rowIndex, exam in enumerate(examDetails):
        for colIndex, key in enumerate(exam):
            index = ui.tableWidget.model().index(rowIndex, colIndex)
            ui.tableWidget.model().setData(index, str(exam[key]))
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @eyllanesc. That actually solve the problem for me and the second solution is great because i don't have to import external library here. But small question. This only generate the first row even though list has 3 dictionaries. Any idea why it happens like that?

Comment: @NipunAlahakoon if you want more rows then you must set it before the for loop: `ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(50)`, or insert it whenever necessary with `ui.tableWidget.insertRow(ui.tableWidget.rowCount())`. I can't help anymore because you don't provide a [MRE], I only limit myself to what you show

Comment: No worries. that fixed the problem for me. thank you very much.